# How to check if a variable is referencing an element in "this" collection?

Tags: java, pointers, collections

Say you have a class that creates a list of numbers. You can add numbers at any position or remove numbers. If I create two instances of that class, `listA` and `listB` I can do the same for both classes. However if I do the following:

```
List<Integer> listA = new PositionList<>();
Position<Integer> a = listA.add(1);
Position<Integer> b = listA.add(7);
List<Integer> listB = new PositionList<>();
b = listB.add(7);

listA.remove(b)
```

I'm not removing `b` from listA because that variable is now pointing to the listB instance. I'm writing a method that is supposed to make sure whatever variable is being operated upon is pointing to the instance I'm specifying. In the case of `listA.remove(b)` I would make sure b is pointing to the `7` I added to listA. Is there some way to check for this? I know the fix for this is to not do that in the first place, but I need to figure out how to do it if I don't have access to making those changes.

Comment: It appears that `PositionList<>` implements `List<Integer>`, in which case `listA.add(1)` should return `boolean`, not `Position<Integer>`. You have a different interface in place there, right?

Comment: Honestly, I've read your question several times but I fail to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @lexicore Sorry, I'm a bit new to this and it's hard to articulate exactly what I mean. What I'd like to know is how to test which of the two lists, `listA or listB`, is the variable `b` pointing to. I know it's pointing to listB, but I would like to test that with code. Something like `isInstance()` or `getClass()`, if it exists.

Comment: @Alex Please explain what does "pointing to" means exactly.

Comment: @lexicore By pointing to I mean `b = listA.add(7);` is referencing the integer 7, which I added to listA. After `b = listB.add(7);` it's now referencing the integer 7 added to listB. I wrote `listA.remove(b)` to illustrate that if I try to remove `b` from listA, it will actually remove it from listB because that is where `b` is now "pointing to"

Comment: @Alex Ok, what does "referencing the integer `7`, which I added to `listA`" mean technically? Provided an instance of `Position<Integer>`, how do you check which integer in which list does it reference?

Comment: @lexicore The add method, which is implemented inside listA and listB will add a number to the specified list and return the position to which it was added. It works similarly to appending values to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to add list reference to `Position<T>` that you return, and checking it inside `remove` method:

```
class Position<T> {
    private final T v;
    private final int p;
    final PositionList<T> owner;
    public T getValue() { return v; }
    public int getPosition() { return p; }
    Position(T val, int pos, PositionList<T> o) {
        v = val;
        p = pos;
        owner = o;
    }
}

class PositionList<T> {
    ...
    public void remove(Position<T> p) {
        if (p.owner != this) {
             ... // Error! Throw an exception or exit
        }
        ...
    }
}
```